# How to successfully install ColdFusion on windows 8.1 Enterprise?

Tags: coldfusion-11

I am experiencing problems with the installations of Adobe ColdFusion 11 on windows 8.1 enterprise, no error appearing and the software does not even run to the next window just flip off

Comment: Please check the installation log for errors, if any? Do you see the folder structure created? Do you see the windows services created? Did you try the start the service from command prompt?

Comment: No log error appearing because the software does not run for a second. once I double click its pop up then go dead.

Answer (score 0):

So, it doesn't launches at all. Please try the following Steps:-

1. Launch Command prompt as Administrator.
2. Navigate to the location for ColdFusion 11 installer.
3. Type the command as shown below in the command prompt and press
   Enter

   [image]
4. The installer will launch. Follow the onscreen steps further.

Comment: Thanks Anit. let me try it straight away.

Comment: Hi guys,still can't install.

Comment: KumR, I did do like you suggested there but no positive answer.

Comment: Could be a problem with the installer. Can you try with a fresh download from www.adobe.com? Also, please try running the same installer on a different server. You may not need to complete the installation, bit just check, whether the installer launches at all or not.